# Is there the event that triggered after all Control_Prerender events

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to construct and show a notification if some errors happen in page life cycle.

Usually, I use `Page_PreRender` event for last changes but there are also many `Control_PreRender` events which called after `Page_PreRender`.

Is there the event that triggered after all `Control_PreRender` events that can be used to construct and show a notification?

Or if I find and use the latest `Control_PreRender` event, is guaranted that the order of all `Control_PreRender` events will stay the same?

Answer (score 0):

based on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) Technically PreRender is your last chance to tweak the page or control before it turns into HTML stream. another alternative you can use jquery document ready to show your notification.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for show notification
  // can by via ajax or just common javascript
});
```